# Rails production, trilogy can't connect to remote db but mysql2 can

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, puma

Trying to switch our production Rails 7.1.3 server from `mysql2` to `trilogy` to connect to two dbs:

- our *remote* mysql db at `DB_IP_ADDR` on a separate DO droplet
- our *local* solid_cache mysql db on our webserver DO droplet at `PRODUCTION_IP_ADDR`

Because of the [known issue](https://github.com/trilogy-libraries/activerecord-trilogy-adapter/issues/64) with trilogy not being able to use mysql 8's `caching_sha2_password`, I've already reverted `mysql` to use `mysql_native_password`, on both the remote mysql server and the production (localhost) cache mysql server:

```bash
# on DB_IP_ADDR

mysql> ALTER USER 'us'@'PRODUCTION_IP_ADDR' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

```bash
# on PRODUCTION_IP_ADDR

mysql> ALTER USER 'us'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'cache_password';
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Our `config/database.yml`

```yaml
production:
  primary:
    adapter:  trilogy
    database: remote_production_db
    host:     DB_IP_ADDR
    username: us
    password: password
    socket:   /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
    encoding: utf8
  cache:
    adapter:  trilogy
    database: our_solid_cache_db
    host:     127.0.0.1
    username: us
    password: cache_password
    socket:   /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
    endoding: utf8
    migrations_paths: "db/cache/migrate"
```

The *local* cache db connects fine with trilogy, but the *remote* db connection fails with

```bash
ActiveRecord::DatabaseConnectionError: There is an issue connecting to your database with your username/password, username: us. (ActiveRecord::DatabaseConnectionError)

Please check your database configuration to ensure the username/password are valid.
...

Caused by:
Trilogy::BaseConnectionError: 1045: Access denied for user 'us'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (Trilogy::BaseConnectionError)
```

I've double-checked the password and it's right: If i switch the `database.yml` back to `adapter: mysql2` without changing anything else, both db connections are OK.

I notice the error message identifies the attempted user connection as `'us'@'localhost'`, but the request is not coming from `localhost`, it's coming from `PRODUCTION_IP_ADDR`.

Is there something special I need for Trilogy to connect to a remote db, or identify a remote user?

Comment: If the mysql username has localhost in it, then your code connects to a local mysql instance, not to a remote one.

Comment: Thanks. That was the mystery - the mysql username did not have `localhost` in it! But your comment put me on the right track, thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

The remote host needs **either** a `host` IP, or a `socket`, but not both. The presence of a `socket` param makes it assume it's on `localhost`.

I deleted the remote `socket` and it connects OK.

I assume `mysql2` makes a different assumption from the same params. It must ignore the `socket` or something.